# Process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Tags: android, android-studio, java-8, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

On running an Android Application on Android Studio gives me the following error:-

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

I have also added the `multiDexEnabled true` to my `build.gradle` file. But still it gives me the error.

I am not sure for what reason it shows me this error. I had also gone through the following links, But haven't got anything that could help me to solve my issue.

[Process 'command usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java' finished with non-zero exit value 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32903900/process-command-usr-lib-jvm-java-8-oracle-bin-java-finished-with-non-zero-exit)

[Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'. com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29460443/execution-failed-for-task-appdexdebug-com-android-ide-common-process-proces)

[Android with Gradle (Java finished with non-zero exit value 2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29296650/android-with-gradle-java-finished-with-non-zero-exit-value-2)

[Execution failed Process command /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java finished with non-zero exit value 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32860806/execution-failed-process-command-usr-lib-jvm-java-8-oracle-bin-java-finished-wi)

Any help would save me my world. Thanks in advance.

Comment: minimum to target ,install complete sdk versions and change build tool and sdk version.... rebuild your project....

Comment: @ExceptionLover I didn't got what you want me to do?

Answer (score 1):

This issue made me pull out lots of my hair.
In my case, it turns out I had incompatible Firebase library versions.

I would suggest running through your dependencies once more for good measure, and make sure **libraries that should be the same version are**, **libraries that depend on a particular version have that version**, and you have **not redefined dependencies** that already transitively come from another dependency you have added.

Answer (score 1):

In my case going to File | Project structure... | Platform settings | SDKs and changing JDK home path to an alternative worked.